# Resque retry retries without delay

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque, resque-retry

This is the code that I have

```
class ExampleTask
    extend Resque::Plugins::ExponentialBackoff
    @backoff_strategy = [0, 20, 3600]
    @queue = :example_tasks
    def self.perform
      raise
    end
  end
```

I am running into a problem where, whenever I enqueue this task locally, Resque seems to retry the task immediately without respecting the backoff strategy. Has anyone ever experienced this problem before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

upgrading to 1.0.0 actually solves this problem.

Answer (score 0):

For any future readers, the first integer in the array `@backoff_strategy` is how long Resque-Retry will wait before retrying the first time. From the [github readme](https://github.com/lantins/resque-retry#exponential-backoff):

```
key: m = minutes, h = hours

              no delay, 1m, 10m,   1h,    3h,    6h
@backoff_strategy = [0, 60, 600, 3600, 10800, 21600]
@retry_delay_multiplicand_min = 1.0
@retry_delay_multiplicand_max = 1.0

The first delay will be 0 seconds, the 2nd will be 60 seconds, etc... Again, tweak to your own needs.
```